# Comparar linhas de um arquivo txt em Python

Tags: python

Estou tendo dificuldades em criar um script em Python para comparar linhas de um arquivo txt.

Basicamente, preciso percorrer um arquivo e verificar se um campo é igual a outro, lembrando que não pode se comparar toda a linha, e apenas uma parte, no caso o que eu desejo comparar é o primeiro valor antes dos dois pontos(:), segue o código:

```
from collections import Counter
arq = open("arquivo.txt")
linhas = arq.readlines()
for linha in linhas:
    x = linha.split(':')
    print(Counter(linhas)[x])
```

Estou recebendo o erro: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Desse jeito, eu iria verificar se algum campo foi repetido, e então deletaria essa linha.

Answer (score 0):

```
resultado = {}

with open('arquivo.txt') as arq:
    for linha in arq.readlines():
        x = linha.split(':')
        if len(x) == 2 and not x[0] in resultado:
            resultado[x[0]] = x[1]

with open('arquivo.txt', 'w') as arq:
    for i in resultado:
        arq.write(f'{i}:{resultado[i]}')
```

Esse novo codigo cria um dicionário e conforme vai lendo o arquivo adiciona (se não existir essa key) um item no dicionario que a key seria antes do ":" e o valor seria depois

depois disso ele abre o arquivo em modo de escrita (sobrescrevendo o arquivo original), passa por cada item do dicionario e escreve.

Answer (score -2):

O método split retorna uma lista! na linha `x = linha.split(":")` a variável **X** recebeu então um valor de lista... quando você escreveu `print(Counter(linhas)[x])` voce literalmente criou uma nova lista com um valor unico de outra lista dentro dela...

é como se vc tivesse feito [ [ X ] ]

você poderia deixar assim:

```
with open('arquivo.txt') as arq:
   linhas = arq.readlines()

for linha in linhas:
    x = linha.replace('\n', '').split(':')

    if len(x) == 2:    
        if x[0] == x[1]:        
            print(x[0])
```

- primeiro eu utilizei o with junto com o open, essa é uma boa prática que impede que seu arquivo seja corrompido.
- Armazenei as linhas em uma lista e rodei um for passando por elas e atribui na variavel **linha**
- Rodei o método `.replace('\n', '')` para impedir que ele considere o "enter" no final da linha como um carácter e acabe atrapalhando o funcionamento do código
- Rodei o método `.split(':')` que transformou a string em uma lista
- Realizei um `if len(x) == 2` para saber se realmente tinha um ":" na linha
- Por ultimo realizei um `if x[0] == x[1]` para então saber se as duas divisões da string eram semelhantes!!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela solução, porém, acredito que tenha entendido errado, eu preciso comparar uma linha com a outra, exemplo:  

123:Lucas  
123:Silva  
1234:Teste  

No caso, a linha 2(123:Silva), seria deletada, pois já tem o ID 123 na linha 1, então ficaria apenas a linha 1 e 3 no arquivo de texto. Eu preciso comparar as linhas, e não comprar os valores de cada linha.